# Cacti in combat

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, weapons, flora

Which are the boundaries in size of an army and/or the style of warfare and combat of applying equipment made out of cacti for warriors?

I can think of:

- bats, maces, spears and similar handheld weapons equipped with cactus either on the end or in their entirety
- guns or at least bows shooting smaller cactus projectile
- armors and shield, for example, to perform tactics like Testudo of the ancient Roman warrior

If real life cacti are unfeasible, then consideration of harder cacti (=non-existing IRL, but possible in an alternate world) may come into account in answers.

Comment: Harder as in "iron harder" 'cacti' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flail_(weapon))?

Comment: @SJuan76 harder as "wood harder" would be enough I presume - well, up to a certain point. For such a weapon you linked, it's much simpler. It's a great idea, thanks for showing

Comment: My point is that, once you know enough metallurgy to make a nail (not that difficult), you can just put a bunch of nails in a pole and you have a way better weapon than any cactus could ever be. You could still use cactus as a cheap way to make passing through an area difficult.

Comment: That is the point. Cheap, easier (yet a bit longer) to reproduce, and if it's not like the real-world counterparts but harder, then it might be extremely beneficial. I mean, just consider the enormous costs (in money and in effort) of iron.

Comment: China Miéville's novels [Perdido Street Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perdido_Street_Station) and [The Scar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scar) include cactus *people* - sapient, walking and talking cacti. They may suggest some more detailed ideas.

Comment: I think if you're talking about your own made up ones that don't exist in real life, you can make up whatever you like so that they would be useful how you see fit...

Comment: @colmde hence the [reality-check] tag.

Comment: > *guns or at least bows* If you can afford those, why bother with cacti? If you are low enough on resources to use cacti - maybe sling is what you need.

Comment: Pants.  No-one would want to fight you.  How do you hurt a guy who already wears cactus pants?  I think I am going to write a country song about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you might want to go the other way and have very processed cacti bits, not lobbing fresh cacti around.

Cactus are, pretty much, area affect weapons when fresh.  That is, there's no easy way to safely use them, they are trying to attack *everyone*, everyone.  A cactus that can easily be de-thorned where held, will lose its needles quickly, one that can be easily mounted (on a flail or mace) will come off just as quickly.  One that's harder to work with will bite the hands of it's craftspeople or wielders.  Most cacti are pretty soft and squishy inside when fresh (heavy to wield or throw, but squishy when landing, is not a good weapon combo), and would be hollow and brittle if dried whole, so they won't make good blunt weapons.  And the cacti coming apart is just as likely to mess up its wielder (throwing off their weight and balance into a lunge or slipping in the guts) as their opponent.  Think about it, thorned or fleshy plants are really not used as weapons or to add random spikes (rose canes, or thistles, or anything) for many of the same reasons, they are just as likely to work against, as for, their wielder.

If your opponents have horses, or maybe even war-dogs, you might try out your cacti as bombs instead of, or as well as, sling-stones - use a heavy glove, or a scoop (in atlatl style), to lob little knobs of cacti at the animals - again, much more exposed skin and less armor, and animals will additionally spook and shy at the pain and be much more distracting than humans getting hit.  Humans are more covered, and more disciplined, and less likely to flail around to give secondary effects unless they're exposing a lot of bare skin.  But no one will be carrying their cacti, it will be more like sling stones which using what ammunition is to hand (with ammunition resting on the ground), since it can affect both sides, will make footing harder for everyone, and may waste resources that could be used another way (medicinal or food (or water) value of the plants)

On the other hand, you can probably do some nice, tricky things with them once processed.  Darts, as I mentioned, with long and sturdy thorns (bound and tufted with fibers or even hairs).  They can be weighted for throwing, or a blowpipe can be made (just needs to construct a tube).  They can create quite a bit of force, and even unpoisoned can be deadly even to humans when aimed at eyes, throat, and with a bit of luck, major organs (if they happen not to hit bone).  Add to the fact they can be aimed quite well if the blowpipes are long, and will penetrate even pretty small gaps in armor, and they can be quite a threat.

You may be able to process some sort of armor or shields out of one of your cacti varieties - maybe a cactus skin that can be carefully dried or processed (and possibly layered or laminated) to make something of a leather-like consistency, or weight bearing stems carved to size and dried hard to a woody texture for lacquered style armor, maybe fibers can be extracted from a stringy variety for a woven cloth (which can be layered or laminated for another type of armor).  People have worked with wicker or hide shields and armor, it's just a matter of finding the right raw materials.  If not cacti, well, people will likely have the hides and leather and possibly bones, from the local food sources, to make up the rest of their tools and clothes (frames for shields, or sinew cordage, or glue) - even if cactus parts are more abundant, they likely can only be used for *some* uses.

It may also be possible to make poisons - to tip your darts in, or maybe to make powders, or lob burning dried cacti and watch them hallucinate from the smoke, whatever.  It depends on what kind of cactus you've got, and what's in it - and what your people are willing to use, since smoke is, again, an area effect weapon.  Actually, you can take dried cactus to use torches/fire as a weapon directly - burning strategic resources, or signaling, or surprise attacks/mind games, fire isn't often directly used on the battlefield because the fire is limited by fuel and time (and can be turned on its wielder) but it has its place if your people are canny.

If your cacti are harder, wood-like... then you're gonna get wooden weapons.  The random spikes won't stay, as they will cut both ways and make it hard to work with, so it won't matter for the weapons that they're "actually" cacti (unless the collect the needles for something else, like darts, or manually reattach after the weapon is crafted, which is not really that different from adding wood or bone spikes.

Back to questions of size and use -  your army or weapon size will depend on the amount of craftsmanship left over after survival (essentially, your industrialization).  Since this is processed stuff, it can be crafted during down-times, saved year to year, and readied in advance for battles - you're not dependent on finding cacti in the right areas and amounts and timelines as you would if using fresh cacti.  I would assume you're using cacti because abundant, so it's growth and availability shouldn't be a limiting factor - but processing, drying, and crafting the weapons will be time consuming, even if they will also last quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

In a world were armor and weapons are made out of cacti. I’m going to make two assumptions. Cacti are being used because of a lack of other resources (wood and metal are rare/nonexistent), and that they are real life cacti.

**Size of an army:**
The two limiting factors are number of people willing to fight, and the number of fresh cacti available.

**Style of warfare:**
My understanding of mini house cactus anatomy says the needles are the hardest part.

My limited experience eating dried cactus snacks say that dried cactus is still rather soft and squishy.

Thin cacti could be used as makeshift spiked clubs if the handle area is cleared of needles.  These extra needles could be implanted in the club or in a pair of gloves. I don’t imagine the cactus club will survive multiple strikes. I also cannot imagine a warrior carrying more than one(maybe two) at a time. So I imagine combat between two groups would start off with a cactus dual of sorts and once they break it becomes an all-out brawl. (this is where the needle glove might be useful)

Larger cacti could be cut into armor like objects. Like the club I cannot imagen that the cactus armor will last too many strikes. I would not dry the armor out, you want it thick enough to stop a needle. The main purpose of the armor would be to stop the initial needle club attack. If it survives the initial attack it may disway your opponent from grappling you in the brawl segment of the battle.

One thing to keep in mind is that there will be a lot of broken cacti bits on the ground. I think good boots would be a necessity. Slip proof and cacti caltrop proof.

Comment: I read the beginning of this question in cinema trailer narrator voice `In a world were armor and weapons are made out of cacti...`.

Comment: You can buff your cacti club by putting a hard rod inside and buff it even more by running a rope around it, tightening cacti flesh to said rod. Club like this will definitely survive multiple strikes. Bones for rods and hair/tendons/guts for ropes would be available for your army anywhere.

Also this means that neither army has armor. If water is not a problem - soak cacti with venom. If water is a problem - use it on spikes. You are guaranteed that something will enter the bloodstream.

Comment: @Daerdemandt
Poison and venom can be useful weapons. Personally I feel they are too much of as double bladed weapon. It can be too easy to accidentally poke yourself with one of the many needles.
I did not think of bones as a building material. that's a good call, if that is plentiful enough to you, you many not need cacti at all.

Comment: > *Poison and venom can be useful weapons* Stopping power is usually negligible though and that's what makes difference in meelee.

Answer (score 2):

You could have cacti with poisonous needles. Your warriors could use them to their advantage.